# Add product stock information to product repository

Tags: magento2, product, stock

When working with the **ProductRepository** in Magento 2 and the results of the `getList` method what is the "best" way to add extra information to the results?

For example in the default 2.1.7 setup you will get the following data.

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 1
    [attribute_set_id] => 4
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => sample-product-1
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2017-06-06 11:28:00
    [updated_at] => 2017-06-06 11:28:00
    [status] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [name] => Sample Product 1
    [meta_title] => Sample Product 1
    [meta_description] => Sample Product 1 
    [options_container] => container2
    [url_key] => sample-product-1
    [gift_message_available] => 2
    [meta_keyword] => Sample Product 1
    [price] => 2.3000
    [quantity_and_stock_status] => 1
    [tax_class_id] => 2
)
```

But how would you recommend retrieving the stock quantity information ?